# how to find birth year from age input?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a Python program that would take a user's age in years and will return their birth year. I tried to use the datetime module and find the current year, then subtract the age from the current year. Unfortunately, for certain birth months it's not giving me the right year. For example, if an user who was born in April 9 in 1990 inputs his birthday as 32 (since it's still January 2023, not April), he will get 1991 as his birth year which would be wrong, because he does not turn 33 until April 9, 2023. Also there are leap years. I don't know how to determine the birthday only from taking age as input. Any suggestions? Or is there any alternate ways of doing it?
This is my code:

```py
from datetime import date 

age = input("What's your age?")
today = date.today()
current_year=today.year
birth_year=current_year-age
```

But if I try giving 32 as age input for someone who has not yet turned 33 in the January 2023 (will turn 33 in April), then it will give me 1991 as the birth month, which is wrong.

Comment: It's not possible to get someones birth year given just their age in years as an integer, there will nearly always be two possible answers

Comment: you need to request age and month of birth

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In addition to the age, enter also a month. And depending on whether this month has come yet or not, calculate the year of birth.